# PowerShell filter specific form from string

Tags: powershell

I have a long string which contains letters, numbers, and other symbols.
I need to filter everything that matches the form `number.number.number`. For example `1.0.90` should pass the filter (it's a version number).

Afterwards, I need to convert the number after the last period (in the above example - `90`) to a number which I can manipulate.

I didn't find any good explanation out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the version number and capture the revision number for extraction (via the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0#matches) `$matches`):

```
... | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '\d+\.\d+\.(\d+)'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $revision = [int]$matches[1]
}
```